# Calling a clojure Leiningen plugin from another plugin

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using lein (leiningen) with clojure - and writing a plugin to automate some common tasks. I would like to have my plugin depend on, and call another plugins functionality - but I am not sure how to do that without something hacky - any ideas?

Comment: You can see a simple example here: https://github.com/vbauer/lein-jslint Plugin "lein-jslint" uses plugin "lein-npm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the other plugin as a dependency of the one you are working on, then require its namespace in your code and call the functions you need.

```
;;; in project.clj
(defproject your-plugin "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
   :dependencies [... [other-plugin "1.2.3"] ...]
   )

;;; in src/leiningen/your_plugin.clj
(ns leiningen.your-plugin
  (:require [leiningen.other-plugin :as other])
  ...)

... (other/foo ...) ...
```

See [lein-margauto](https://github.com/kyleburton/lein-margauto) (which depends on [lein-marginalia](https://github.com/fogus/lein-marginalia)) for an actual working example.